# What is the recent etymology of the American expression "mosey''?

Tags: etymology, linguistics

The two Spanish prevailing explanations that get repeated are the Spanish *vamos* and the British dialectical *mose about*. These explanations are at least two decades old and predate the internet digitization of substantial material. And, from an American perspective, not very convincing.

Comment: What is "metymology", and what do you mean by "recent"?

Comment: The OED agrees that the origin is uncertain: *Of uncertain origin.* **perhaps related to mosy adj. or muzz v. (see discussion s.vv.), although this is perhaps less likely if ‘to go away quickly or promptly’ is the original sense.** -- Notes
It is also uncertain whether there is any connection with the following: *1902 [Worcestershire] A gooas a mausin' about jus' as if a worn't quite right.* H. Kingsford in English Dialect Dictionary (1903) vol. IV. 167/2

Comment: I would guess that "mosey", in the US, was popularized by the use of the term in 1950s TV westerns.

Comment: The expression "mosey [directional preposition] home" dates back to at least 1875. I could post an answer if I knew what the question were asking.

Comment: Is there a recent definition of mosey that you're talking about? I'm mostly familiar with its use in westerns, which take place in the 1800's.

Answer (score 4):

**mosey** (v.)

> *Slang* (originally U.S.)
>
> *Intransitive*. Originally: to go away quickly or promptly; to make haste (now *rare*). Later usually: to walk in a leisurely or aimless
> manner; to amble, wander. Frequently with *along, off, on, over*.
>
> **1829** **Mosey**, to move off.
> *Virginia Lit. Museum* 30 December 459
>
> **1870** I hain't got time to be palavering along here—got to..**mosey** along.
> ‘M. Twain’, *Curious Republic Gondour* (1919) 57
>
> **2000** The hunters **moseyed** back to the woods for the afternoon hunt.
> *Denver Post* 26 November c6/2
> [OED]

> The word ***mosey***, as does *vamoose*, probably derives from the Spanish
> *vamos*, "we go." Some lexicographers offer, however, the possibility it descends from nineteenth-century itinerant Jewish peddlers often
> named (or pejoratively called) Moses; other scholars find its origin
> in the leisurely and relaxed gait of antebellum, Southern Negroes
> ("Mose" a not-uncommon moniker) who had little to gain by hurrying to
> the hot fields. The earliest theory I've seen comes from John Russel
> Bartlett in his wonderfully jolly (although I think not so intended)
> *Dictionary of Americanisms* of 1848, which contends the word ***mosey*** (he termed it "a low expression") derives from an Ohio postmaster
> named Moses who absconded with considerable federal receipts. But
> absconding is no longer—if it ever was—at the heart of **moseying**.
> [William Least Heat-Moon; *Roads to Quoz: An American **Mosey***](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Roads_to_Quoz/JIWqvxMwdXAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20word%20mosey%20comes%20from&pg=PT257&printsec=frontcover)
> (2008)

It may be that the origin is lost to us for good and that all we have left are conjectures by hombres fixin' to spin a good yarn—although the "Ohio postmaster" origin does fit the original meaning of the word according to the OED. That, pardner, would leave open the question of how *moseying* went from *skedaddling* to *ambling* away. Ironic/humerous use, perhaps?

Comment: Note that, in Spanish, _vamos_ may literally mean "we go", but in this case it is used as "let's go", just as in English.